# Specify column headers when creating excel file via Perl

Tags: excel, perl

I have some data to put in excel file. What I need is to rename headers of columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqaOK.png

Im using use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel; module.
Can someone give me idea how to do that?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. I believe they are not saved in the xls or whatever file. For example, if i turn them off completely and move the file to another host, they show up again. I believe you would have to create your own header line below that, hide the original headers in your Excel and use custom sort or whatever you wanted to change the header line for in the first place.

Comment: It's not possible. Those are only the coordinates for Excel so it knows which columns you are talking about. You cannot rename them in Excel. As DeVadder said, add your own line of headers below that if you want custom headers.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible in Excel so it isn't possible with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.